# Controlling Components on Title Page

Tags: titles

I have a simple document that begins on page 2 and identifying information on the title page. The following code demonstrates this:

```
\title{Merchant Agreement Skeleton}
\author{Merchant}
\date{\today}

\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=0.55in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespace
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}


\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

I'd like to be able to include a figure on the title page and generally be able to have identifiers along the lines of this document. [image]

Comment: Your link does not provide anything but errors right now... And `titlesec` is meant for chapter etc. titles, not for the titlepage

Comment: I don't see a link but your code will certainly not compile as posted. Since your question is not about a compilation error, you should ensure that it works before posting.

Comment: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)